# iOS Simulators are not working in Xcode 6.1.1?

Tags: ios, xcode6, simulator, xcode6.1-gm-seed

Iam able to run my project in iPad and iphone but when i tried to run it in iPad simulators
but then i got this error .

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Users/apple/Documents/releaseAPICON2015/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

please check this link for screenshot

[Error](http://postimg.org/image/84ma6h02h/)

Please tell me how to get back all simulators in xcode 6.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to link SenTestingKit.framework in you iOS project. You cannot use OS X binaries in iOS Simulator apps as they are not compatible.

On older versions of iOS, you would encounter runtime errors (incorrect values or crashes). On iOS 8.0, this became a link-time error.

You need to build a version of SenTestingKit.framework for iOS. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: can u answer my this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863507/uitableviewcell-image-size-changing-on-click-of-cell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863507/uitableviewcell-image-size-changing-on-click-of-cell