# Prevent UITableViewCell image view from changing size when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set the `imageView` on a standard `UITableViewCell` from a remote source using a placeholder. I have this issue regardless of using `SDWebImage` or `AlamofireImage` as the library.

Here is how the cell appears after the initial load:

[image: How the image appears in the cell after the initial load]

Then, once the cell has been tapped/reloaded it appears as this:

[image: Image shrinks and moves the text when tapped/reloaded]

In the storyboard, I've adjusted the **row height to be 60 points** instead of the standard 44 points. If I return the height to the standard 44 points, the issue is no longer present.

I believe this issue is more related to custom height of the cell rather than the library providing the placeholder. I made an issue on [AlamofireImage in case it was a problem with the library](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/issues/30) but it turns out this is not the case.

How can I have the image set at the right size initially, or prevent a resize from occurring upon reload?

Here is the code from my `UITableViewCell` subclass. Note that the issue occurs even if I remove the frame inset code inside of `layoutSubviews`.

```
class CategoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var category: Category! {
        didSet {
            self.updateCategory(category)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.imageView?.frame = CGRectInset(self.imageView!.frame, 10, 10)
    }

    private func updateCategory(category: Category) {
        self.textLabel?.text = category.name

        self.imageView?.sd_setImageWithURL(category.largeImage ?? nil, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "DefaultCategory"))
    }
}
```

---

I've now also set the following overrides on the table view controller, bu it hasn't had any effect.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60;
}
    
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Are you doing anything "funky" with the `UITableViewCell` subclass (if there is one)? Any conflicting constraints in interface builder?

Comment: Try setting the tableview's `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to 60. or `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I've added the code from my subclass. Also, there are no conflicting constraints.

Comment: I've added the two height delegates as shown above, but they don't have any effect.

Comment: @Dwight I've the same issue, had you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), and this post helped me [SDWebImage fixed width cell images](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2011/11/sdwebimage-fixed-width-cell-images/).

Here is my solution, just save the initial frame of the imageView, text and detailText, and restore it on the layoutSubviews()

```
class MoreTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var imageFrame: CGRect? = nil
    var textFrame: CGRect? = nil
    var detailTextFrame: CGRect? = nil

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if imageFrame == nil {
            imageFrame = imageView?.frame
            textFrame = textLabel?.frame
            detailTextFrame = detailTextLabel?.frame
        }

        if imageFrame != nil {
            self.imageView?.frame = imageFrame!
        }

        if textFrame != nil {
            self.textLabel?.frame = textFrame!
        }

        if detailTextFrame != nil {
            self.detailTextLabel?.frame = detailTextFrame!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jeez, I had to search the *whole* web to find the hint for `layoutSubviews`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to leave a comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Hence, the "answer".

I remember running into this problem before and it was due to me not setting proper constraints for it on my UITableViewCell XIB. Once I set it to a fixed width/height and pin it to the edges of the parent view, the problem resolved itself.

Comment: is right. If this doesn't solve your problem, then please check UIImageView content mode.

Comment: The table view cell in my storyboard is just an empty, standard `UITableViewCell` - I'm not able to set any constraints on it as I haven't altered it by adding any subviews.

Comment: I see. My guess here: You are accessing the default imageView in UITableViewCell where its frames are set as read-only property which in this case it is set to a default 44 points after redrawing. Refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129461/uiimageview-resizes-automatically

Comment: also, @Abdul Yasin mentioned checking the content mode, that could help as well, if you do not want to go down the custom cell direction.

Comment: @rach So am I correct in understanding that the `imageView` of the default `UITableViewCell` only works at the standard height of 44 points, and if I wanted it to work at 60 points I would need to design my own view in interface builder to make it work?

Comment: Yes. That is my assumption based on the question you described.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `cell.setNeedsLayout()` after setting Cell's image view!

```
MenuController.shared.fetchImage(url: item.imageURL) { (image) in
        if let image = image {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imageView?.image = image
                cell.setNeedsLayout()
            }
        }
    }
```